# Regex: match two occurrences of the same unknown substring

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying write a regex to match two occurrences of an unknown substrings in a string.

For example: `11=11` should be valid since 11 occurs twice with equal sign in the middle. `ashg=hgasfa` is also valid since `hg` occurs twice. `' or 1=1 '` should be valid since `1` occurs twice.

More specifically, in my project, I'm trying to match all strings data where two sides of the equal sign contain the same strings.

---

I remember using variables like `$1` or `$2` when modifying [Apache route](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html) [files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/images/rewrite_backreferences.png) or even writing Sublime Text snippets. How can I implement this functionality? Can I write a regex like `.* $1=$1 .*`? Is this even possible to accomplish with Regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use back-referncing (like `\1`) in-order to refer those characters which are present inside a particular group index.

```
>>> s = 'ashg=hgasfa'
>>> re.search(r'([^=]+)=\1', s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(2, 7), match='hg=hg'>
>>> re.search(r'([^=]+)=\1', 'ashg=hgasfa').group(1)
'hg'
>>> re.search(r'([^=]+)=\1', '11=11').group(1)
'11'
>>> re.search(r'([^=]+)=\1', ' or 1=1 ').group(1)
'1'
```

`([^=]+)` in the above captures one or more characters (but not of `=` symbol) which exists just before to `=` symbol and then the regex engine checks for the existence of same set of characters  next to `=` symbol. If yes, then it would return a match object, else it won't.